# Solution to multiplied heat equation

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, heat-equation

I know how to solve the standard heat equation but if I were introduce a function g of safe and time into the mix as:
$$
\partial_t f(t,x)= g(t,x)\partial^2_x f(t,x),
$$
How can I solve this problem?  Is it possible to use a clever change of variables in x?

Comment: If $g$ is separable you can, otherwise in general I'd imagine not.

Comment: @Gregory So I should make a substitution of the form:
$$
\partial_t\tau(t)=g^{-1}_1(t) \, \partial_x^2 X(x)=g_2(x),
$$
if I assume that $g(t,x)=g_1(t)g_2(x)$ or something similar?  How could I determine the correct change of variables

Comment: If you could write $g(t,x) = g_1(t) g_2(x)$ You can then just do separation of variables $f(t,x) = T(t) X(x)$ and solve. This is a standard technique, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables#Partial_differential_equations (section on PDEs)

Comment: How can I deal with the case that $g_2(x)$ is non-constant (but can be assumed to be positive)?

Comment: From what I said previously, write $f = T(t) X(x)$ then you would have $T' X = g_1(t) g_2(x) X''$ if you put all terms involving $t$ and $x$ on different sides $\frac{T'}{g_1 T} = \frac{X'}{g_2 X} = C$ where $C$ is a constant. It must be constant because the LHS and RHS contain terms involving only $t$ and $x$, respectively.

Comment: How can I explicitly solve the second order ODE in such a general form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case $1$: $g(t,x)=a(t)b(x)$

The PDE is obviously separable.

Let $f(t,x)=T(t)X(x)$ ,

Then $T'(t)X(x)=a(t)b(x)T(t)X''(x)$

$\dfrac{T'(t)}{a(t)T(t)}=\dfrac{b(x)X''(x)}{X(x)}$

Case $2$: $g(t,x)=h(ax+bt)$ , $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$

Let $\begin{cases}x_1=x\\t_1=ax+bt\end{cases}$ ,

Then $f_x=f_{x_1}(x_1)_x+f_{t_1}(t_1)_x=f_{x_1}+af_{t_1}$

$f_{xx}=(f_{x_1}+af_{t_1})_x=(f_{x_1}+af_{t_1})_{x_1}(x_1)_x+(f_{x_1}+af_{t_1})_{t_1}(t_1)_x=f_{x_1x_1}+af_{x_1t_1}+af_{x_1t_1}+a^2f_{t_1t_1}=f_{x_1x_1}+2af_{x_1t_1}+a^2f_{t_1t_1}$

$f_t=f_{x_1}(x_1)_t+f_{t_1}(t_1)_t=bf_{t_1}$

$\therefore bf_{t_1}=h(t_1)(f_{x_1x_1}+2af_{x_1t_1}+a^2f_{t_1t_1})$